# vlan eth0.20 removed after physical disconnection

Tags: networking, ethernet, lan

vlan is succesfully created by /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0.20
iface eth0.20 inet static
    address 192.168.2.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 0.0.0.0
    vlan-raw-device eth0
```

after if i removed the lan wire and reconnect again vlan is removed.
Kindly help to restore the vlan interface.

**Before disconnection:**
[image]

**After disconnection:**
[image]